# C - Print all numbers with same count of set and unset bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I have to print numbers with max `N` bits where `count of bits set to 1 = count of bits set to 0`. I ignoring leading zeros. I thinking that this applies only when count of bits is even.

My code:

```
int power(k) {
   return 1 << k;
}


void print_numbers(int n){

   n      -= (n % 2); // FOR EVEN COUNT OF BITS
   int exp = 1; // EXPONENTS WILL BE ODD (2^1, 2^3, 2^5, ...)

   while (exp < n) {

       int start        = power(exp);
       int end          = power(exp + 1);
       int ones         = (exp + 1) / 2; // ALLOWED COUNT OF 1

       for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
          int bits_count = 0;

          for (int j = 0; j <= exp; j++){ // CHECK COUNT OF 1
             bits_count += ((i >> j) & 1);
          }
          if (bits_count == ones){
             printf("%d\n", i);
          }
       }
       exp += 2;
   }
```

For `N = 12` this function print 637 numbers. Is this solution correct or am i wrong? Any idea for more efficient or  better solution?

Comment: Looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, assuming the code works.

Comment: @MLN96 What does this mean   count of 1 = count of 0? How many bits should a number have when N is equal to 12?

Comment: for example number 240 is 8 bit number and has 4 set bits (1) and 4 unset bits (0) . I have to print all numbers which are 1 bit long, 2 bits long, 3 bits long  .... 12 bits long.

Comment: So are you counting the bit-length starting at the highest-order one-bit? In other words, is the first bit of every number always a `1`?

Comment: @MLN96 Can you speak the human language?! One more what does mean count of 1 = count of 0?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: he means that the number of bits set to 1 is equal to the number of bits set to 0, such as `11001100`.

Comment: @rici 10, 1001, 1010, 1100, 100011, 100101 ...

Comment: can you have numbers like 0011 ?

Comment: MLN96: "every number starts with a 1" is, IMHO, a clearer statement than a partial list of examples which *seem* to conform to that simple description, as evidenced by @Thomas's question :)

Comment: @rici I was too lazy to write a sentence :(

Comment: Anyway, if you mean that all numbers start with a 1, then the number of "balanced" numbers of length `2k` is C(2k, k-1) (where C is the binomial function), and the sum of C(2k, k-1) for k from 1 to 6 is indeed 637. FWIW.

Comment: @Thomas i ignoring leading zeros

Comment: @MLN96 You should implement a program using ricis comment regarding the binomial function. Your solution has a time complexity of `O(2^N) ` and using the binomial function as suggested by rici you get a time complexity of only `O(N^2)`.

Comment: This is related to simply counting all bits in a number, which has been well researched, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation; also, if you are using gcc, there is a single command, `__builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)`, which is translated to a single machine instruction if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this, which is a totally different approach (and perfectible) but works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void checker(int number)
{
    int c;
    int zeros = 0;
    int ones = 0;

    for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        if (number >> c & 1) 
        {
            ones++;
        }
        else if(ones > 0)
        {
            zeros++;
        }
    }
    if(zeros == ones)
    {
        printf("%i\n", number);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    for (c = 4095; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        checker(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which get me `638` values (including 0)